Load a GeoJSON file as a URL parameter using Mapbox's Geojson.io API
https://geojson.io/#map=2/0/20
For the above website is it possible to load a GeoJSON file from a local drive via a URL parameter? Something like this, but works:
https://geojson.io/#file=MyData.geojson
There are a few API options here, including raw data but no option for a file:
https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io/blob/main/API.md

Why has @Vince edited my question title to read as a statement? I thought Stack Exchange required them as questions.
From the pop-up help when starting a new thread:
"Ask a public question"
"Title*
Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person"

Yes, you can plop the GeoJSON object into the URL, as long as you urlencode it.

data=data:application/json,
Open the map and load a chunk of GeoJSON data from a URL segment directly onto the map. The GeoJSON data should be encoded as per encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(geojson_data)).
Example:
http://geojson.io/#data=data:application/json,%7B%22type%22%3A%22LineString%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B%5B0%2C0%5D%2C%5B10%2C10%5D%5D%7D


You've provided an example direct from the link I provided in my question, to a list of examples that I said did not include a solution to my problem.
I'm unsure why.
